# imagecopymerge() For two images Already in Server (watermark usage)

Tags: php, image, watermark

I have two photos already in server, trying to use one for WATERMARK..

I am using the below script:

```
<?php

$watermark  = "../images/watermark/watermark.gif";
$image  = "../images/mainphoto.gif";


$padding        = 0; 
$opacity        = 100;  


$watermark_size     = getimagesize($watermark);
$watermark_width    = $watermark_size[0];  
$watermark_height   = $watermark_size[1];  

$image_size     = getimagesize($image);  
$dest_x         = $image_size[0] - $watermark_width - $padding;  
$dest_y         = $image_size[1] - $watermark_height - $padding;

if(!$image  || !$watermark) die("Error: main image or watermark could not be loaded!");


imagecopymerge($image, $watermark, $dest_x, $dest_y, 0, 0, $watermark_width,        $watermark_height, $opacity);

?>
```

I am getting the following error:

Warning: imagecopymerge() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in /home/neatbuz/public_html/asite_service/inc_watermark.php on line 26

please help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$image = imagecreatefromgif ( "../images/mainphoto.gif" );
$watermark = imagecreatefromgif ( "../images/watermark/watermark.gif" );
```

i'd recommend to use png instead of gif images

Comment: Thank you cpfaffinger, I did as you advised, even I used PNG for the watermark file, and original i left GIF, the problem is solved, but when I view the Master image after watermarking with above code, nothing happened, not watermarked?!!! I even chmod to 777, still the watermark did not work. PLEASE ADVISE